# Create flask endpoint only for testing

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am learning flask to create endpoints using flask-restful and flask-sqlalchemy.

There is one configuration property named `testing` in the flask.

Is there any way in flask-restful or in the flask, using that we can create an endpoint that will only available if `testing` config property of flask app is true.

Comment: Why would you want such an endpoint? What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In the email confirmation testing, we can use this endpoint to confirm email and automation testing can be used meaningfully.

Comment: You should do it with the actual endpoint. If you create another endpoint, you would no longer be testing your actual endpoint

Comment: With Python you can create a smtp server for testing very easily: https://muffinresearch.co.uk/fake-smtp-server-with-python/  If you do not want to do that, you could mock sending the emails when in test mode. Or you set an environment variable on testing and catch his in your route.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the flexibility that Python provides.

```
if app.testing:
    @app.route('/only-for-testing')
    def only_for_testing():
        ...
```